# 7zip update archive command creates undesirable tmp files

Tags: file, zip, 7zip, tmp, temporary-files

I have an .exe which includes update and add 7zip operations.
Update operation creates .tmp files which are not deleted after compressing the file.

Also, their names are *.zip.tmp1, *.zip.tmp2 and like that...

How can I prevent creating these .tmp files or provide deleting these files after zip operation?

Comment: Do you have the sources of your exe tool?

Comment: Yeah, I have the sources @NicolasR.

The working command line is like that --> C:\xyz\7z u C:\xyz\backup\xyz.zip C:\xyz\abc\*

And it creates xyz.zip under the location C:\xyz.

Comment: What kind of sources is it? C# project?

Comment: It's a cobol project @NicolasR

Comment: Wow... So I won't be able to help, sorry